# CICS application gives different result/output compared to when used with CEDF

Tags: cics

I have a problem where my CICS application gives a different result compared to when run with CEDF. I have a program where I make some updates to a db2 table, write to vsam. When I run the application, the tasks always fails. But when I run it in CEDF, tasks are successfully done, no errors. Somebody got any idea why this happens?

Comment: I think it may help people answer the question if you mention how it fails - what response codes, abends, log messages, etc.

Comment: The pauses that CEDF is inserting during execution might be helping. Like Ben says it would be interesting to see what’s going on in the trace to see why the application is failing

Comment: I once had a problem with wrong results from a CICS-program that disapeared once I used CEDF or DebugTool to analyze it. The reason turned out to be that after a CICS didn't properly restore some floating point registers used by the (back then) new compilers - and the debugging aids did change the task-switching behaviour. Most probably this is not related to the OP's problem, but just to illustrate that such low-level problems can be pretty annoying and hard to track.

Comment: Thanks guys, I already solved it. It's because I am writing to a VSAM twice with the same primary key. So I just used EXEC CICS DELAY to separate the time of writing of the two records.